# Pandas: Summing values of n rows with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is how my dataset looks,

```
   Temp (C) Rel Hum (%) Wind Spd (km/h)   St
0       8.1          81               4  0.0
1       8.1          79               4  2.0
2       8.1          78               4  3.0
3       8.1          80               4  3.0
4       8.1          78               4  2.0
5       8.1          78               4  3.0
6       8.1          81               4  3.0
7       8.1          78               4  2.0
8       8.1          80               4  3.0
9       8.1          78               4  2.0
10      8.1          77               4  3.0
11      8.1          81               4  3.0
12      8.1          82               4  2.0
13      8.1          78               4  3.0
14      8.1          79               4  3.0
```

What I want is to take sum of first n-rows of "St" and replace the n-rows with the single row where the sum of n-rows of "St" will be placed. Also, the single row will contain average values of n-rows, like "Rel Hum(%)".

That will look something like this with n=5,

```
   Temp (C) Rel Hum (%) Wind Spd (km/h)   St
0       8.1        79.2               4  10.0
1       8.1          79               4  13.0
2       8.1        79.4               4  14.0
```

I have tried different solutions like this,

```
df['St'] = df['St'].groupby(df.index // N).sum()
```

How I can use groupby() or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) instead `sum` and not assign to column, but to new `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

N = 5
df = df.groupby(df.index // N).agg({'Temp (C)':'mean',
                                    'Rel Hum (%)':'mean',
                                    'Wind Spd (km/h)':'mean',
                                    'St':'sum'})
print (df)
   Temp (C)  Rel Hum (%)  Wind Spd (km/h)    St
0       8.1         79.2                4  10.0
1       8.1         79.0                4  13.0
2       8.1         79.4                4  14.0
```

Comment: But applying this returns an error. ```DataError: No numeric types to aggregate```

Comment: @RajatRaja - Answer was edited by `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Comment: Yeah. this edited one worked perfectly. I tried ```df["St"] = pd.to_numeric(df["St"], downcast="float")``` for each column, with also worked. But this seems more efficient.